# Create an Eclipse Java project in command line

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to automate the creation of an [Eclipse Java project](https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-New-Java-Project-in-Eclipse).

I need a way to do this using the command line.

I found many articles for this for CDT, but not for the java one.

Is there a way to do that with Java IDE?

Comment: In Eclipse a Java project requires at least the two XML files `.project` and `.classpath`. Do you want to add the project to a workspace in addition?

Comment: Can you provide a link to those CDT articles? Maybe that processes can be adapted for Java projects. Otherwise I think you could use Maven and the Maven Eclipse plugin to create Maven-based Eclipse projects from the command line (it's no longer maintained though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Principles of my solution:

- get templates of `.project` and `.classpath` files from existing projects
- in a Shell script, use and customize this template to create new Project required files
- in Eclipse, import filesystem folder as a Project (now possible due to created files)

Below is only the relevant part/end of the script, where `.project` file is created.
Note: I did not need a `.classpath` file in my case, thus only importing a Project, not Java Project.

```
# name: the local Eclipse Folder name I give as script arg
# Create Eclipse .project
projectFile="${name}/.project" ;

# below EOF's content comes from an existing real .project file
echo $( cat <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
  <name>${name}</name>
  <comment></comment>
  <projects></projects>
  <buildSpec></buildSpec>
  <natures></natures>
</projectDescription>
EOF
) > ${projectFile};
echo "✓ ${projectFile} created" ;

# Create Eclipse .classpath if needed (in case of Java project, not needed for default Project)
...
```

After this:

- open Eclipse
- "File > Import... > Existing Projects into Workspace"
- select the project folder

Comment: Perfect, Thank you.